# Effective field theory with coordinate dependent "axion"

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-anomalies, effective-field-theory, chemical-potential, axion

Suppose the theory of fermions interacting with EM field and the axial 4-vector $b_{\mu}$:
$$
S = \int d^{4}x \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}(i\partial_{\mu} + eA_{\mu} +\gamma_{5}b_{\mu})\psi
$$ 
We want to integrate out the fermions in order to obtain the quantum effective action $\Gamma[A,b]$. As we know, it is anomalous, i.e. contains the chiral axial anomaly.

First, suppose $b_{\mu} = \text{const}$. We can eliminate the explicit term $\gamma_{5}$ by appropriate **local** chiral transformation
$$
\tag 1 \psi\to e^{-i\gamma_{5}x_{\mu}\cdot b^{\mu}}\psi
$$
Instead, the anomalous jacobian will be generated:
$$
\tag 2 S_{eff}= \frac{1}{16\pi^{2}}\int x\cdot b \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}
$$
Suppose now that $b_{\mu}$ varies in spacetime (but remains physical, i.e., observed). Then the transformation $(1)$ leaves the gradient term in the initial action, namely,
$$
\tag 3
\Delta S = \int d^{4}x x^\mu \partial_{\nu}b_{\mu} J^{\nu}_{5}
$$
We can make another chiral transformation, which eliminates this term, but in fact new ones will be generated.

**My question** is following. As we see from $(2)$, the field $b\cdot x$ plays the role of the axion field. Moreover, if we choose $\mathbf b = 0$, then the remaining $b_{0}$ may play the role of chemical potential $\mu_{5}$. In the case of varying with space-time $\mu_{5}$ we can't use the effective action $(2)$ for describing the dynamics of EM field, because of $(3)$. However, in many literature sources the action $(2)$ is the only which people use.

So, what is the correct description of "axion" anomalous dynamics in the case of space-time dependent "axion" field $x\cdot b(x)$?